# Python append more than one element

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I have a list(T) of 6500 images(arrays) that I am using for image classification, and I would like to see how increasing the data affects the accuracy.

So, starting from n=2000 images, I am thinking of having a loop that will add 500(n+=500) images at each iteration till it reaches 6500 and therefore compare the accuracy between 2000, 2500, 3000, ... 6500. I have simplified the problem below by having a list of 20 elements.

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

My second list (`slist`) contains the first 9 elements of the first list (`lst`).

I am trying to add 2 values to `slist` at each iteration, starting from `lst[9:]`.  I know rather than using `append`, `extend` should be used to add multiple values at once. However, I couldn't find a way to do it.

In the following code, one element is added to `slist` (from `lst`) at each loop.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
slist = lst[:9]
for i in lst[9:]:
    slist.append(i)
```

How can I add 2 or 3 elements simultaneously at each loop? An example output would be:

```py
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Much better now, the background especially explains the previously meaningless initial 9. But why should the output of your example only go to `[..., 4, 5]`? For your real data you say "till it reaches 6500", i.e., till the end. Also not clear is why you accepted an answer that doesn't at all do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, missed this comment. the example going to `[...,4,5]` is just an example of how I expect it to look like. Eventually, I want to go till the end in some cases and have an `x` number of iterations in other cases. Hence, the last code I published for review.

For the code I accepted, it was a mistake. took it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
  16,17,18,19,21]

slist= lst[:9]
s,f=0,2
while True:
    slist.extend(lst[9:][s:f])
    print(slist)
    s+=2
    f+=2
    if len(slist) >= len(lst):
        break
```

It prints out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `extend`:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
slist = l[:9]
for i in l[9:][::2]:
    if i == l[9]:
        slist.extend(l[9+i: 9+i+1])
    else:
        slist.extend(l[9+i-1: 9+i+1])
    print(slist)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
```

Comment: Copy that. Cheers!

Comment: @KaiserMusa Edited my answer, please check it out, remember to upvote and accept if it works :-)

Comment: Didn't do what it was supposed to at all. I see you changed it now. Still looks wrong, depends on the elements "working" as indices just as needed. And never appends the last 0.

Comment: Actually, still clearly doesn't do what it should, as your output even shows. Your first extension is `8, 9` when it should be `0, 1`.

Comment: @KaiserMusa I'd propose to first write a proper problem specification.

Comment: @KaiserMusa I changed my code, should be much better now

Comment: Still wrong output (you now have `8, 9, 9, 0` in there) and you still have that dependency on elements working as indices.

Comment: Now your first extension is just `0` instead of `0, 1`. And you still have that dependency on elements working as indices. I don't understand why you keep doing that. Is it to mock the OP for their bad original problem description? See the updated question, as expected that toy data is just like that for easy visibility, in reality they have *images* instead of magically weirdly self-extension-describing indices that you pretend they are.

Comment: @superbrain
Can I have review in the code below?

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
  16,17,18,19,20]

iter = 9
while True:
    print(lst[:iter])
    iter+=2
    if len(lst) <= iter:
        print(lst[:iter])
        break
```